# How to call a procedure from a package?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I would like to call a procedure from a package:

```
exec TEST_Procedure.TEST_Procedure_PR(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3, Parameter4, Parameter5);
```

The Parameters are all quoted and I have 5 IN Parameters and 1 OUT (Ref Cursor).

However when I call the procedure in the package directly I get my values. 
If I call the procedure from the cmd line with SQL I get the error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_Procedure_PR'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are only passing 5 parameters, not 6. Can you please post your  procedure code?

Comment: How do you call it from the command line? Did you define your OUT variable?

Comment: You can't use `exec` to execute such procedure. I'd advise you reading a bit about [Anonymous blocks](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-mar/o21plsql-242570.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your package just code the procedure call without the `EXEC` statement, which is only required in SQL*Plus. For example,

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY YOUR_PACKAGE AS

PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE IS
BEGIN
   TEST_Procedure.TEST_Procedure_PR(Parameter1,
                                    Parameter2,
                                    Parameter3,
                                    Parameter4,
                                    Parameter5);
END SOME_PROCEDURE;

END YOUR_PACKAGE;
```

Best of luck.